# Connect to non-standard couchbase ports for integration testing

Tags: integration-testing, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to set up automated integration-tests for a Spring Boot application that connects to couchbase. I want to test against a fresh containerised database using random available ports so that we don't need to worry about port collisions on developer machines or in continuous integration environments.

So far I've created a test that uses `com.palantir.docker.compose.DockerComposeRule` to spin up a [couchbase docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchbase/) that exposes the standard ports on random available ports. However, [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.couchbase.CouchbaseProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/couchbase/CouchbaseProperties.java) doesn't expose any properties for ports.

I can see that [org.springframework.data.couchbase.config.CouchbaseEnvironmentParser](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blob/3.1.2.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/couchbase/config/CouchbaseEnvironmentParser.java) suggests that there is some way to set the ports. I haven't been able to work out how to use it though. Has anyone else been able to do this?

This is what my test looks like so far:

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
public class BiscuitRepositoryIT {

    private static final int COUCHBASE_PORT = 8091;
    private static final String COUCHBASE_SERVICE = "couchbase";

    @ClassRule
    public static DockerComposeRule docker = DockerComposeRule.builder()
            .file("src/test/resources/docker-compose-couchbase.yml")
            .projectName(ProjectName.random())
            .waitingForService(COUCHBASE_SERVICE, HealthChecks.toHaveAllPortsOpen())
            .build();

    @Autowired
    private BiscuitRepositoryConfig config;

    @Autowired
    private BiscuitRepository biscuitRepository;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() {
        DockerPort couchbase = docker.containers()
                .container(COUCHBASE_SERVICE)
                .port(COUCHBASE_PORT);

        log.info("couchbase ports: {}", couchbase);

        // TODO update integration-test properties file with the ports
        // before the spring context starts.
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        biscuitRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void insertBiscuit() throws Exception {
        Biscuit digestive = Biscuit.builder().name("digestive").manufacturer("biscuitCorp").build();
        Biscuit persistedBiscuit = biscuitRepository.save(digestive);
        assertThat(persistedBiscuit).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(digestive, "id", "version");
    }
}
```